# UI freezes when sending image over tcp

Tags: c#, bitmap, tcpclient, tcp, tcplistener

I write this code to send screenshot to multiple connected clients.Works fine on clients end but freezes the UI of application on server side.I don't understand what cause that problem.

```
public void LoopClients()
{            
    while (_isRunning)
    {
        TcpClient newClient = Server.AcceptTcpClient();

        Thread t = new Thread(new 
         ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClient));
        t.Start(newClient);
    }
}

public void HandleClient(object obj)
{
    TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;

    BinaryFormatter binaryformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    while (client.Connected)
    {

        MainStream = client.GetStream();
        binaryformatter.Serialize(MainStream, GrabDesktop());

    }
}

private static Image GrabDesktop()
{
    System.Drawing.Rectangle bound = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(bound.Width, bound.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(bound.X, bound.Y, 0, 0, bound.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    return screenshot;
}
```

Any help or suggestion to improve the code or fix to solve the problem would be great help.

Comment: I think `while (_isRunning)` might be the offender here, unless `LoopClients` has it's own thread it will be running on the UI thread

Comment: No  have tried to work other way, still freezez.

Comment: What do you mean by `other way`

Comment: Remove the while(_isRunning) boolean statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the server is listing for new clients to connect with an iterative loop, this might block your main UI thread. Run that using a new thread.

```
public void LoopClients()
{       
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() =>
    {   
        while (_isRunning)
        {
            TcpClient newClient = Server.AcceptTcpClient();

            Thread t = new Thread(new 
             ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClient));
            t.Start(newClient);
        }
    }).Start()      
}
```

Note: *Its not always required to have `new threads` for `HandleClient` however its not a probelm*

Comment: And the problem goes away. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Hamxa please mark this as answer if this has solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that you are creating a new Thread in a while loop?
It means you will create a lot of Threads.
Remove the while loop and everything will be fine.

Comment: It just reduce the server load, except for that every thing works fine now.

Comment: You are creating Threads in a loop. It means you will create the endless amount of threads. Thread is an expensive resource. If the goal is to create a responsive UI application, one thread is enough.

Comment: @ArtyomA. The code in that loop only continues whenever `Server.AcceptTcpClient()` gets a new connection, though. It will only create a new thread for every new incoming connection.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I didn't pay an attention that there is blocking call in the while loop. Thanks.